# CSS.supports in Edge returns incorrectly for items that are supported

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

CSS.supports() in Edge returns incorrectly for properties that *are* apparently supported.

```
console.log(CSS.supports("( filter: blur(20px) )"));
console.log(CSS.supports("filter", "blur(20px)"));
console.log(CSS.supports("( backdrop-filter: blur(20px) )"));
console.log(CSS.supports("backdrop-filter", "blur(20px)"));
```

Logs:

> ```
> true
> true
> false
> false
> ```

The last two are incorrect, as `backdrop-filter` does actually work in Edge.

However this works as expected:

```
@supports (backdrop-filter: blur(20px)) {
    body { border: 20px solid red; }
}
```

Am I missing something, or is CSS.supports broken in Edge? And how can I detect support for `backdrop-filter`?

Comment: What is returned when you do console.log(CSS.supports("-webkit-backdrop-filter", "blur(20px)"));. I know when I last checked, Edge required the `-webkit-` prefix to use `backdrop-filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Edge does not support the unprefixed `backdrop-filter` property; it only supports `-webkit-backdrop-filter`.

If your CSS works, it's either being prefixed at runtime by a script like -prefix-free (although -prefix-free itself is not known to support `backdrop-filter`), or postprocessed by something like Autoprefixer, silently adding the `-webkit-` prefix for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation below, Currently CSS Backdrop Filter only supported with the -webkit- prefix (not -ms-) in MS Edge browser.

[CSS Backdrop Filter](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter)

Because of that reason, It returns false.